# How can I use SQL to break comma-separeted values into new rows

Tags: sql, database, csv

I have the following dataset example:

| Name: | Qualities: |
| --- | --- |
| Adam | Authentic,Cool,Young |
| Bob | Serious,Old,Authentic |
| Carl | Cool,Athletic,Hardworker |

And I need to use SQL to turn this dataset into the following:

| Name: | Qualities: |
| --- | --- |
| Adam | Authentic |
| Adam | Cool |
| Adam | Young |
| Bob | Serious |
| Bob | Old |
| Bob | Authentic |
| Carl | Cool |
| Carl | Athletic |
| Carl | Hardworker |

Can someone give me a hand on that? I have no clue how can I get this done.

Hope to find it out soon!

Cheers!

Comment: Hi @RodrigoMoro, can you share the DBMS you're currently using?

Comment: Hopefully the purpose here is permanently **fixing** the schema... because comma-separated data in a column really is a _BROKEN_ design.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Name, value AS Quality FROM <dataset>
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(Qualities, ',')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can used STRING_SPLIT for string values.

Please see more informaton.

https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-string-functions/sql-server-string_split-function/

```
SELECT 
    Name,
    value Quality
FROM 
    <TABLE NAME>
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(Qualities, ',');
```